# Why is it “der” Person in this sentence?

Tags: grammatical-case, definite-article

“Du gibst **der** Person an der Kasse das Geld für die Karte.”
In this sentence, *Person* is feminine, singular, accusative, and yet the definite article is *der* rather than *die*. Why is that? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you correctly noted, it cannot be singular accusative, it is dative. The verb “geben” can take an accusative object, denoting what is given, and a dative object, denoting to whom. In this case the accusative object is “das Geld für die Karte”, the dative object is “der Person an der Kasse”.

Comment: Oh my gosh, yes, of course. Thank you!